# Picasso and Holders in Listview with variable height

Tags: android, listview, adapter, picasso, android-viewholder

I'm using a listView where my items use the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_imageView" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Content -->
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cell cell;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
        cell = new Cell(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(cell);
    } else {
        cell = (Cell) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // ... Some stuff with other views ...
    Picasso.with(_context).load("http://...").fit().centerCrop().into(cell.backgroundImageView);

    return convertView;
}

static class Cell {
    @Bind(R.id.background_imageView) ImageView backgroundImageView;
    // Other views

    public Cell(View view){
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

This is the result when I scroll:

[image]

It looks like Picasso is resizing the image using the height of the old Holder.imageView.
I don't have this problem when I don't use Holders.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like wrapping the Picasso call into `cell.backgroundImageView.post()` does the work :

```
cell.backgroundImageView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Picasso.with(_context).load("http://...").fit().centerCrop().into(cell.backgroundImageView);
                }
            });
```

Picasso is called once the view is rendered/resized and can apply the right measures to the imageView.

Comment: this seems to work well - upvoted, how did you find this out?